# cordova IOS permanent storage if app is deleted

Tags: ios, cordova, local-storage, settings

we're developing a cordova based ios app which is being limited to a select number of login credentials (id pins). Im looking to create an internal lookup to do this. Basically if the user enters the correct pin id (that is saved inside app json file) then they gain access. If they enter incorrect pin 5 times then the app is locked.

Without local storage etc, is there anyway to keep the storage file on the ipad even if the app is deleted? thus in-turn if the user re-installs the app, it will find out that the user has tried previously and stay locked. I understand that localstorage gets wiped when the app does, but I want to prevent this small loophole.

The client in this case didnt want the lookup/login to be server-side which would of been soooo much easier.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is no way to store such data persistent on the Device.** You are able to save data as long as the application is installed on the device. If the user deletes the application, all storages will be cleared independently from which kind they are (webSQL, indexedDB, LocalStorage).

These are storage options for you: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Comment: You're welcome. As far as i know this is also not possible with a native iOS application.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to store string values permanently in iPhone application.

http://www.programmingcrew.in/2015/08/save-value-in-keychain-ios-application.html